# unable to get useUnsafeHeaderParsing to work

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have a server that sits behind an Incapsula Web App Firewall, which alters the headers sent to IIS. When I perform a specific request I get the following error from IIS: The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=CR must be followed by LF. This behavior is also described in: http://www.dragonblogger.com/fix-live-writer-protocol-violation-error-cr-lf/

According to this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65ha8tzh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx I should be able to accept these headers by setting the useUnsafeHeaderParsing to true. So I tried adding this to the web.config in the virtual directory from which the specific request should be handled:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <settings>
            <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
        </settings>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

After restarting IIS it still does not work. I also tried adding this to the c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\framework\config\web.conf but it did not work either.

Does anyone have any idea what I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to connect Azure Application Insights to one of our websites (also "protected" by Incapsula) we encountered the same response header violation. Setting the useUnsafeHeaderParsing to true didn't work either.

Consulting the Incapsula support desk helped us out: it seems that Incapsula is adding an irregular cookie to the response to identify the visitor as a bot or as a human visitor. The addition of the irregular cookie the to the response can be the cause of the response header violation. Incapsula also has Javascript classification, so we let them disable the irregular cookie and enable the Javascript classification.

This is how we solved the violation error.

Comment: Hi Bas, thanks for your answer. In the meantime we stopped using Incapsula so I have no way of confirming whether this resolves the issue. However, I had made another attempt at contacting their support and they suggested something similar so I guess this is the right approach. I would expect Incapsula to support IIS out of the box though.